# What are these hardware components, and how do I control them?

Tags: cpu, hardware, code

My father received a video card in the mail last week. He gave it to me and I dismantled the card to get to just the video player and other components.

[image: Components]

The labels here are based on my experience tinkering with it. I don't have any hardware experience to speak of. I plugged this into my Mac through the USB and found one folder, VIDEO, within which was the video played through the card. It was a `.mov` file. I tried replacing it with a random `.mov` file on my drive, but I got a `Incompatible File Type` message on the screen.

There are no other files or folders on the device (hidden or otherwise), beyond what Apple put in for Finder's indexing. It shows up as a FAT-32 drive.

I've been trying to figure out how to access the chip to change what filetypes it accepts or to put in some custom code, but how would I get into it? All I can see currently is the flash-drive section, not any executables to tamper with.

The three main black *areas* (I could use some proper terminology here) of the CPU (?) are:

- "hynlx" 512A KOR (I guess Korea)
- SAMSUNG 031 PCBO
- ATJ2273B-C

**Update**: Here is the [data sheet](http://pulkomandy.tk/ATJ227x/Datasheets/ATJ227X_Datasheet_V1.0_101126.pdf), but this doesn't get me any closer to accessing it.

Comment: Did you try to figure out what codec the video was using?

Comment: Also, "integrated circuits (ICs)".

Comment: The video codec, according to VLC, is H264 (MPEG-4 AVC)(part10)(avc1). I guess that explains why my personal video isn't working, but again how would I go about changing the SOC to accept it?

Comment: You would have to rewrite the firmware on the chip. This is not something for a novice to do.

Comment: @amess reencode your video into the same codec and container format.

Comment: Also, Hynlx is actually Hynix, as in Hynix Smeiconductor. A very common memory manufacturer.

Comment: did you manage to acces this cpu some how ? i have the same problem and i can't figure it out

Comment: I got the same thing, I got it working with a mp4 from an iphone6 just fine. Nothing else needed besides dumping the movie into the root. My version they hardwired the on-off closed, so I had to just short it every time I wanted the movie to play.

Comment: Hate to be the bearer of bad news, but you need significant EE skills to be able to do what you're asking, this is way beyond someone with "no hardware experience to speak of"

Comment: +1 for trying though! What you lack in skills you make up for in ambition.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you've identified the subsystems correctly. On the main PCB, the "black areas" are individual chips.

> "hynlx" 512A KOR (I guess Korea)

This is an SDRAM chip, used by the firmware on the SOC in general, and in particular as a frame buffer for the decoded video.

> SAMSUNG 031 PCBO

This is a flash EEPROM chip, which contains both the firmware for the SOC and the video file.

> ATJ2273B-C

This is the main processor (system on chip, or SOC).

It contains a general-purpose CPU, along with USB, SDRAM, audio and video display controllers, and it "runs the show".